# How to change initial view controller after successful login?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am developing my first app, and I am having trouble understanding how I can use `NSUserDefaults` to change my initial view controller after user has successfully logged in. (Once user has successfully logged in, user will no longer have to log in after launching app) I have read other posts, and googled tutorials, but I honestly cannot understand them.

I am mainly having format issues.

**EDIT:**

Here is the new code I've tried adding:

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var initialViewController: UIViewController



        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

            initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Timeline") as! UIViewController
        }else {

            initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as! LoginViewController
        }

            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

However, every time I try to launch the app, it immediately crashes. The error states:

`2015-08-19 10:30:23.966 Venddy[3451:95841] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'`

If anyone could give me suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. I am new to app development.
Thanks!

Comment: you are using storyboard?

Comment: You are using parse no need to store login status in user defaults.we can get status from PFUser.currentUser(), check the status and do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You should set it in `AppDelegate.swift` file inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {     

   //SET INITIAL CONTROLLER
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController: UIViewController
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let login = userDefaults.objectForKey("loginSuccess") as! Bool //your condition if user is already logged in or not
    {
       // if already logged in then redirect to MainViewController

        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainController") as! MainViewController // 'MainController' is the storyboard id of MainViewController 
    }
    else
    {
       //If not logged in then show LoginViewController
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as! LoginViewController // 'LoginController' is the storyboard id of LoginViewController 

    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 return true
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Do I have to incorporate PFUser.currentUser? Forgot to mention that I am using Parse backend.

Comment: I dont know parse. You can try it by putting different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this something like this

You just add LoginSignup view controller to your storyboard and then you set "Storyboard Id" to "loginVC". After that, in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you check if the user logined or not.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let logined = ?
    var vc: UIViewController?
    if !logined {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginVC")
    } else {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    }
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Don't forget in target's setting in "Deployment Info" remove value of "Main interface"

Answer (score 0):

**Code for Swift 4.2 and 5 code:**

```
           self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

           if(loggedIn){

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboardVC")

            } else {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")
            }
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```